# Android image scale to Listview items

Tags: android, image, layout, android-listview

I am setting up a ListView that should hold rows, with an image thumbnail and text. I would like to show 5 rows on the screen, and scale the images to the available space depending on the device.

I have made the following layout xml files. First one holds the ListView, and the second the list item. I am currently setting a fixed size. How could I change the layout to scale images to adapt to the screen size?

Setting up the ListView:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"" >

    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/gallery"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </ListView>

</FrameLayout>
```

The list item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="horizontal" >
 <ImageView
 android:id="@+id/icon"
 android:layout_width="50dp"
 android:layout_height="50dp"
 android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
 android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
 android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
 android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
 android:src="@raw/pic01" />

 <TextView
 android:id="@+id/textview"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:textSize="20sp" 
 android:paddingTop="5dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think these lines of code will help you.In your adapter class, on getView function put these lines of code

```
    switch (ctx.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi) {
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
                    setImageSize(appIcon, 36, 36);
                    break;
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
                    setImageSize(appIcon, 48, 48);
                    break;
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
                    setImageSize(appIcon, 72, 72);
                    break;
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
                    setImageSize(appIcon, 96, 96);
                    break;
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_400:
                    setImageSize(appIcon, 96, 96);
                    break;
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH:
                    setImageSize(appIcon, 144, 144);
                    break;
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_560:
                    setImageSize(appIcon, 144, 144);
                    break;
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXXHIGH:
                    setImageSize(appIcon, 192, 192);
                    break;
                default:
                    setImageSize(appIcon, 48, 48);
                }
```

here is setImageSize function

```
        private void setImageSize(ImageView appIcon, int width, int height) {
    try {
        appIcon.getLayoutParams().width = width;
        appIcon.getLayoutParams().height = height;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        DebugLog.console(ex, "[UserInfoAdapter]: Exception in setImageSize");           
        EmailDebugLog.getInstance(ctx).writeLog(ex.toString()+ "\r\n[UserInfoAdapter]: Exception occured inside setImageSize");
    }
}
```